# Kotlin Round Up An Integer

Tags: android, kotlin, math

Let's say I have an integer like 588 and
I want to round that number up to 590

Or:

397 -> 400,

233 -> 230

...

Or maybe:

388 -> 400

77 -> 100

Does Kotlin has a function for these kind of situations? Or do I need to create my own algorithm for that? I tried using `ceil()` or `roundToInt()` but I think those are just for rounding doubles.

Comment: not sure what you are rounding up to, next hundred, ten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing arbitrary rounding, so no there's nothing like that built in - only functions for rounding to the nearest integer in various ways.

You could write a basic rounding function like this:

```
fun Int.roundToClosest(step: Int): Int {
    require(step > 0)
    // in this case 'lower' meaning 'closer to zero'
    val lower = this - (this % step)
    val upper = lower + if (this >= 0) step else -step
    return if (this - lower < upper - this) lower else upper
}

println(-5.roundToClosest(10))

>> -10
```

In this case it "rounds up" away from zero, so for negative numbers it increases their magnitude instead of rounding up towards positive infinity. If you want `ceil` behaviour (rounding to positive infinity) I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!